# Revisions API doesn't return all revisions if post has had multiple edits made in quick succession

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, revisions

I am pulling information from the [posts API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts) and then checking the [revisions API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids) for some of these posts. I am noticing that on posts which have had multiple revisions done in quick succession that the revisions API is not quite up to date.

To replicate:

1. Edit one of your own posts and check the [revision API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#page=1&pagesize=100&filter=!9YdnS7lAA&site=stackoverflow&run=true). Input your post Id and hit run
2. Check your revision is there (it should be)
3. Give it 5 minutes (until the grace period has ended) and edit the same post again so that it creates a new revision
4. Check the revision API again and see if the latest revision has come through (I'm finding it's not)

There seems to be a delay and I think it's towards the 10 minute mark in the revision API for edits made in quick succession.

Edits also done within the grace period also don't come through right away until the feed is refreshed and then any changes done within a grace period can be seen in the revision API under.

Is there any reason for the delay?

Comment: When I tested it, no edit showed up until after 5 minutes, not even the first one.

Comment: @BrockAdams I did wonder if that would be the case too. There's definitely a delay of some sort.

Comment: As a slight note, to get round this I now store the `postId` and `revisionId` so that I can check to see if the message has been previously posted and to ignore if it has.